# select query to duplicate same row with one different value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I have a table like below:

```
CId  Name Class
1    vv   A_N
1    ff   B_P
1    bb   C_U
```

I want to run a select query on above result to get the desired output as below:

```
CId   Name   Class
1      vv     A
1      vv     N
1      ff     B
1      bb     P
1      ff     C
1      bb     U
```

Also, I have taken an example above. In real scenario I am having lots of columns and query is so big that I am already using Union all for some other requirement. That's why I don't want to use it again for this requirement.

Comment: the class is it always 2 element ? or you may have multiple ?

Comment: for now... it will always have 2 element. I just want to have the desired output.

Comment: mysql or mssql?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` with `UNION`, e.g.:

```
SELECT CId, Name, SUBSTRING_INDEX(Class, '_', 1)
FROM table

UNION

SELECT CId, Name, SUBSTRING_INDEX(Class, '_', -1)
FROM table
```

Once done, you can wrap this into another `SELECT` and apply `ORDER BY`, e.g.:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM (
    SELECT CId, Name, SUBSTRING_INDEX(Class, '_', 1)
    FROM table

    UNION

    SELECT CId, Name, SUBSTRING_INDEX(Class, '_', -1)
    FROM table
) a
ORDER BY a.Name;
```

**Update**

If you don't want to use `UNION` then the only other option is to change the schema and create another table for `class`.

Comment: i already mentioned that i don't want to use Union/Union All operator again in my query as I am already using this operator for some other need... thanks anyways!!!

Comment: actually the class column is not in table schema.. it is on the fly .. a text string which is conditional.

Comment: Well, then you don't need a query all, it should be handled by your application/display logic and not an SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  *
from    yourtable t
        cross apply dbo.[DelimitedSplit8K] (t.Class, '_') c
```

using DelimitedSplit8K from 
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution if you have fixed format as in example:

```
SELECT a.Cid,
    a.NAME,
    t.class
FROM Product a
CROSS APPLY(    
    SELECT LEFT(class, 1) class FROM @Product WHERE NAME = a.name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT RIGHT(class, 1) class FROM @Product WHERE NAME = a.name
) t
```

OUTPUT:

```
Cid NAME    class
1   vv      A
1   vv      N
1   ff      B
1   ff      P
1   bb      C
1   bb      U
```